# In node.js, which under the sheets inheritance gives .connection.destroy() to the res object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image]
.connection.destroy()

Using a simple `http.createserver` to set the server and `superagent` to make the request I am having trouble understanding the following:

1. Where the `.connection.destroy()` method is coming from
2. How did the  `res` object get it and i couldn't find it documented.
3. Which object as this method definition and how was it inherited by `res` object?

I found myself in a situation before where I was using `req.on` and discovered it was because `req` was an `IncommingMessage` which was `Stream.Readable` which inherited `EventEmmiter` which has the method .on and so `req` had the method .on from this inheritance.

I would like to see that backwards relation for this connection.destroy() on the res object this time if possible.

I am using the "building javascript enterprise applications" book, unfortunately the code isn't well kept on github, the github version is far advanced to the point much of this has been already erased/changed but you can find it on [this github](https://github.com/elfelround/Building-Enterprise-JavaScript-Applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backtracking my steps I found

> res > ServerResponse > .connection > net.Socket >
>   socket.destroy([exception])

[res parameter created by http.createServer is actually a ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) (which I knew already)

[serverResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) implements .connection

> response.connection# Added in: v0.3.0  See
>   response.socket.

which implements [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket), which implmenets .destroy()

> socket.destroy([exception])# Added in: v0.1.90 exception 
>   Returns:  Ensures that no more I/O activity happens on
>   this socket. Only necessary in case of errors (parse error or so).

If exception is specified, an 'error' event will be emitted and any listeners for that event will receive exception as an argument.

I still wondered tho, why not res.connection.socket.destroy()
That must be because connection is an instantiation of the Socket object by constructor and the socket on socket destroy by the net.Socket documentation is just a call to that instantiation as a didactic reference used on the documentation.